# How to allow line break in a long hyperlink in a PDF compiled by latex-dvips-ps2pdf?

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, urls, dvips

I am using `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` steps with `-Ppdf` option passed to `dvips`. The following code snippet

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 100}}

\def\emailA{\url{abcdefghi.jklmn.opqrs.tuvwxyz@tuvwxyz.com}\ }
\def\emailB{\url{jklmn.opqrs.tuvwxyz.abcdefghi@tuvwxyz.com}\ }
\begin{document}
\emailA or \emailB or \emailB or \emailA or 
\emailA or \emailB or \emailB or \emailA or 
\emailA or \emailB or \emailB or \emailA or 
\emailA or \emailB or \emailB or \emailA or 
\emailA or \emailB or \emailB or \emailA or 
\emailA or \emailB or \emailB or \emailA or 
\emailA or \emailB or \emailB or \emailA or 
\end{document}
```

produces the output as follows.

[image]

Is there any trick to fix it?

Comment: Please don't create new "command" tags like {href} unless absolutely necessary. Also, {hyperlink} should be covered by {hyperref}. Instead, I added {line-breaking} for you. ;-)

Comment: @Lockstep: OK. Sometimes a bit difficult to know what tags I should you.  :-)

Comment: Did you try this with pdfLaTeX: it also fails to break all of the lines 'nicely'. There are cases where it's simply not possible for TeX to break lines automatically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even with the help of the `breakurl` package, your example will produce overfull boxes. This is because `breakurl` will only break urls after one of the following symbols `:/.?#&_,;!` and before any ocurrence of the symbol `%`.

To overcome this you have two possibilities: to use `\sloppy` (which will make the spacing look really awful) or to manually insert some spaces in the appropriate places to help the package find a proper break-point for the urls.

In the following example I show a reduced version of your example with three variants: the first one shows the default output obtained with `breakurl`; in the second one, I manually inserted some `\hspaces`, and in the third one I used `\sloppy`. It's up to you to decide which of the two last approaches looks less ugly and is more practical.

I used `draft` to see the overfull boxes more clearly. The code must be compiled through latex.

```
\documentclass[draft,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 100}}

\def\emailA{\url{abcdefghi.jklmn.opqrs.tuvwxyz@tuvwxyz.com}\ }
\def\emailB{\url{jklmn.opqrs.tuvwxyz.abcdefghi@tuvwxyz.com}\ }
\begin{document}

The example:

\emailA or \emailB or \emailB or \emailA or
\emailA or \emailB or \emailB or \emailA or 
\emailA or \emailB or \emailB

\vspace{1cm}

The example with \verb+\hspace+s manually inserted: 

\hspace*{-4pt}\emailA or \emailB or \emailB or \emailA\hspace{3pt} or\hspace{4pt} 
\emailA or \emailB or \emailB or \emailA or 
\emailA or \emailB\hspace{3pt} or\hspace{3pt} \emailB

\vspace{1cm}

The example with \verb+\sloppy+: 

\begingroup
\sloppy
\emailA or \emailB or \emailB or \emailA or
\emailA or \emailB or \emailB or \emailA or 
\emailA or \emailB or \emailB\par
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 42):

Try this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
If you have any questions, please don't hesitate to contact me
at \url{mailto:xport@tex.stackexchange.com}.
\end{document}
```

With `\href`, you need to use `\nolinkurl` in the second argument.

```
\href{mailto:xport@tex.stackexchange.com}{\nolinkurl{xport@tex.stackexchange.com}}
```

Comment: @xport --- Can you use `pdflatex` instead?

Comment: It seems `\nolinkurl` does the trick without even using `breaklines=true`.  Maybe the latter is default now?

Comment: Also, `nolinkurl` changes the font of the text displayed to the document's monospaced font (at least when using fontspec and XeLaTeX).

Comment: Saved my life! Many thanks for that simple cool hint.

Comment: This doesn't really work (unless you use `pdflatex` in which case you don't need this at all); see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377066/line-breaking-with-adjustment-but-no-hyphenation).

Comment: @IanThompson (I'm just here to thank you for your elegant solution.)

Comment: It doesn't work for me inside the `letter` environment.

Comment: @quant_dev --- Please post a new question with an example code that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 10):

I finally found a solution, that might be of interest to all the ones having problems with displaying long URLs in LaTeX:
I had a little chat with Vilar (the maintainer of the `breakurl`-package) and he was able to extend the breaking possibilities of his package they way I suggested.

Therefore the new option `anythingbreaks` in the newest version does the links look good as they keep in range of the textborder.

---

See for yourself:

Completely without:

[image: without]

---

Standard behavior:

[image: breakurl]

---

Anythingbreaks:

[image: option anythingbreaks]

Look also at my question here: [Biblatex: URL-breaking not working in DVI-mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107507/biblatex-url-breaking-not-working-in-dvi-mode)

Comment: Note that this answer is not a duplicate: it discusses the new `anythingbreaks` option.

Comment: Hi, could you update the answer with the correct way to use the option `anything breaks`?

Comment: @otmezger Just use `\usepackage[anythingbreaks]{breakurl}` in your preamble. That's it.

Comment: Simply including that line throws errors for me: `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \headerps@ {/burl@stx null def /BU.S { /burl@stx null def }de...l.311 }`

Answer (score 7):

I found 2 solutions for breaking long URLs.

The first one unfortunately doesn't work with `hyperref`.

```
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
```

This will break long URLs after hyphens, which is mostly ok. But since `hyperref`uses `url`somehow, there's a conflict activating the `hyphens`-option

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package url.
```

If somebody has an explanation (or solution) for me, I'd be glad.

---

The second solution works fine. I haven't researched it intensely, yet. But it should be a clean solution as only the characterlist for linebreaking is manipulated an neither measures nor mechanisms are influenced. (I'd appreciate it, if someone could verify this.)

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
%or \usepackage{url}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto\UrlBreaks{\do\-}
```

The last line adds the hyphen to the list of characters after which an URL is allowed to break. You can expand the list by adding "dos" like `{\do\a\do\b\do\c}` (This would allow URLs to break after a, b, and c, too.)

There's also a list `\UrlBigBreaks`. But I haven't checked it out, yet.

Comment: The first solution is also discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49788/hyperref-url-long-url-with-dashes-wont-break). The solution is to pass the option to `url` using `PassOptionsToPackage` *before* that package is loaded, which may be before `documentclass`.

Comment: This is my preferred option, as it only breaks links on "/" and "-". not in more random places (e.g. ".").

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [`breakurl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/breakurl) package -- page 1 of the documentation includes the answer to your question.

Comment: @xport: it doesn't work because the package can't find a valid character to break some urls. You can use `\sloppy` (it will work now but the document will look awful) or simply insert some convenient blank space before the problematic urls.

Comment: @Gonzalo:  Could you make an example as the answer? I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```latex
\\
```

Lazy answer, but it's working for me, and I'm new in latex:

**BEFORE**:

```latex
\url{http://www.mma.gov.br/port/conama/processos/C1CB3034/DECRETO_SAO_PAULO_59113_2013.pdf}
```

**AFTER:**

```latex
\url{http://www.mma.gov.br/port/conama/processos/C1CB3034\\/DECRETO_SAO_PAULO_59113_2013.pdf}
```

Comment: This breaks the link! Hence you would be redirected to a different URL...

Comment: you are right, but i have no other way for my two column paper :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the \href function twice (or as many times as you link), both linking to the same URL, but the first with the text you want to appear on the first line, and the second with the text you want to appear on the second line. In other words, you decide where the line break occurs. A bit of a bodge but works well for me:

```
(\href{Full URL}{\underline{Text up to the end of line 1}} \href{Full URL}{\underline{Text for the start of line 2}})
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Package Setup:

```tex
\RequirePackage[bookmarks, bookmarksopen=true, plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels, pdfpagelayout=SinglePage, breaklinks = true]{hyperref}
```

### Sample Hyperlink:

```tex
\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/576098/147162}{Link to this answer!}}
```