# URLs out of page margin

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, margins, urls

I am writing a report in LaTeX. I am done with all of the work. Last thing that is remaining is that some of  my references are going out of the margins and I don't know how to handle them. I Googled for a solution but can't find suitable answer. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: How are you writing those URLs?

Comment: with \url command

Comment: See [`hyperref` + `\url`: long URL with dashes won't break](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49788/5764), which suggests loading `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}`.