# Problem with \href for hyphenated web addresses within latex minipage environment

Tags: minipage, hyphenation, links

I am trying to use `\href` to link to a web address that contains hyphens (e.g. http://hyphenated-webpage.com) within a minipage environment, e.g.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
     Web: \href{http://hypehated-webpage}{{\color{blue}Webpage}}
\end{minipage}
```

In my document `\href` works fine within minipage for non-hyphenated addresses, e.g.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
     Web: \href{http://nonhypehatedwebpage}{{\color{blue}Webpage}}
\end{minipage}
```

And hyphenated addresses also work fine outside of minipage, e.g.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
   ...
\end{minipage}

     Web: \href{http://hypehated-webpage}{{\color{blue}Webpage}}
```

But as soon as I include a hyphenated `\href` web address within the minipage environment, the resulting PDF link does not work. It's completely dud.

Any suggestions?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{alltt}

\begin{document} 

\vspace{0.1in}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{alltt}   \rmfamily
Company
Department 
Address Line 1
Address Line 2
Office: number
\end{alltt}

\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{alltt}   \rmfamily
Web: \href{http://www.boredpanda.com/worst-domain-names/}{{\color{blue}Link}}
E-mail: \href{mailto:}{\color{blue}email 1} (Head office) 
        \href{mailto:}{\color{blue}email 2} (Other office)
Company reg: number 
Other Info
\end{alltt}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, can you modify your post to include a [short but compilable test case](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) that lets us reproduce the hyphenation issue with minimal effort?

Comment: No problem - included above with random hyphenated web address. Dan

Comment: You should check similar questions like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49788/hyperref-url-long-url-with-dashes-wont-break

Comment: The panda link works for me, is that the one you meant?

Comment: John, that's the link I mean. It doesn't work at all when I compile the example above... I'm compiling on TexShop (for mac) via typeset > PDFtex > Latex.

Comment: If you get rid of the \begin{alltt} it works.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while to realize that the OP was only using alltt to avoid having to insert `\\` at the end of each line.  Note: adding spaces before `\rmfamily` seems to create an extra line.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{alltt}

\begin{document} 

\vspace{0.1in}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{alltt}\rmfamily
Company
Department 
Address Line 1
Address Line 2
Office: number
\end{alltt}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
Web: \href{http://www.boredpanda.com/worst-domain-names/}{\color{blue}Link}\\
E-mail: \href{mailto:}{\color{blue}email 1}\\
(Head office) \href{mailto:}{\color{blue}email 2}\\
(Other office)\\
Company reg: number\\
Other Info
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: removing alltt]