# Space between words in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, elsarticle

tex code as below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,number]{elsarticle} 
\usepackage{times}%Use Times New Roman Font 
\usepackage[hyphens]{url} %To recognize URLs 
\begin{document} 
\title{Integrated Model for Power Interruption Contracts} 
\author{Lakshmi Palaparambil Dinesh} 
\begingroup %\raggedright 
\bibliography{reference_PowerInterruption} 
%\bibliographystyle{apalike} 
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} 
\endgroup 
\end{document}
```

I see spaces between words or parts of the url with some white spaces after using hyphens with the url package. How to remove the remaning additional white spaces?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I tried to introduce linebreaks in your code sample, can you please check if they are at the correct places?

Comment: Can you try this http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49791/36296 answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot Sam. The line breaks are at the correct places. I tried to indent the code many times, but it was not working for me. I will try again.

Comment: Dis you try the answer linked in the comment above?

Comment: Yes, I did right now. The document is looking so much better, although not perfect. I will add another screenshot of the problem.

Comment: Are you asking why the lines are not justified?

Comment: I tried \raggedright, but it doesn't seem to be helping.

Comment: @samcarter tried intending with the brackets. Could do it.

Comment: What spaces? Remember that the url font is 'mono spaced', which means that each character, no matter how 'little' is designed to take up the same amount of space. An `m` is as wide as a `.`. Compare on separate lines (in a mono spaced font) `mmm`, `.m.`, `m.m`, `i/1`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you gave us no bib file I created one for testing.

Please see the following MWE (package `filecontents` is only used to have bib file and tex code together in one compilable MWE):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@article{feynman,
  title     = {Very High-Energy Collisions of Hadrons},
  author    = {Richard P. Feynman},
  journal   = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume    = {23},
  issue     = {24},
  pages     = {1415--1417},
  year      = {1969},
  month     = {Dec},
  doi       = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.23.1415},
  url       = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.23.1415},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
}
@article{einstein,
  author  = {Albert Einstein},
  title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
             [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  year    = {1905},
  DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004},
}
@Article{Schamb2010,
  Title      = {Properties of the Distant Kuiper Belt: Results from the
                Palomar Distant Solar System Survey},
  Author     = {(Megan E.) Schwamb and (Michael E.) Brown and
                (David L.) Rabinowitz and Darin Ragozzine},
  Journal    = {The Astrophysical Journal},
  Year       = {2010},
  Month      = {September},
  Number     = {2},
  Pages      = {17},
  Volume     = {720},
  Doi        = {10.1088/0004-637X/720/2/1691},
  Timestamp  = {2014.09.21},
  Url        = {http://m.iopscience.iop.org/0004-637X/720/2/1691/pdf/0004-637X\_720\_2\_1691.pdf}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,number]{elsarticle} 

\usepackage{showframe}    % to visualise the typing area and margins
\usepackage{times}        % Use Times New Roman Font 
\usepackage[hyphens]{url} % To recognize URLs 
\usepackage{ragged2e}     % command \RaggedRight

\begin{document}

\title{Integrated Model for Power Interruption Contracts} 
\author{Lakshmi Palaparambil Dinesh} 

This is text with \cite{Goossens, einstein} and \cite{adams}.
\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys

{
%\RaggedRight % <===================================================
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} % apalike
\bibliography{\jobname} 
}

\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image: resulting pdf]

I marked the resulting white space you do not want with red rules ...  The most elegant way I knew to get rid of them is to use package `ragged2e`, which gives you command `\RaggdRight` to get left justified text with better hyphenation! Please uncomment `\RaggdRight` in the MWE (see marking `<=======`) and recompile.

The result you get is now:

[image]

The red arrows marks the layout changings. For me that solution is much more better than the first ...