# Problem with URL in BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, verbatim, urls

I have a problem with the Apple URL.

`@online` Google works fine, but when I add the `@online` of Apple, it generates the error: `\verb doesn't match its definition`!!!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,natbib=true,sorting=none ,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{library.bib}

\begin{document}

User Interface \cite{Google}.
User Interface \cite{Apple}

\end{document}
```

Bib file:

```
@online{Google,
author = {Google},
title = {User Interface Guidelines from Google},
url = {https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/overview.html},
year = {},
note={Accessed December 30, 2017}}

@online{Apple,
author = {Apple Inc},
title = {Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines},
url = {https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/design-principles/},
year = {},
note={Accessed December 30, 2017}}
```

Comment: Please post a compilable example (full minimal document).

Comment: See if this could be useful to you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49791/101651. Otherwise, edit your question and add a 
•[minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: Your example works well. Why do you use `bibtex` instead of `biber`. Do you have the same error when compiling you example? Do you have an updated version biblatex?

Comment: It works fine now , after adding this :                                \makeatletter
\def\blx@maxline{77}
\makeatother

Comment: That error has been resolved some time ago. You should make sure to update your packages to the newest versions. It is also recommended to switch from BibTeX to Biber (where this problem never occurred in the first place).