# Website as a reference

Tags: cross-referencing

I want to reference a website in a springer paper so when I click on it, it connects to this website. How can I do that?

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[natbib,twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}% <-- new
\usepackage{ragged2e}% <-- new

\hypersetup{draft}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
results obtained with simulated data are presented and discussed. 

\keywords{keyword1 \and keyword1}
% \PACS{PACS code1 \and PACS code2 \and more}
% \subclass{MSC code1 \and MSC code2 \and more}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
The purpose of these notes is to provide an introduction to stochastic differential equations (SDEs) (LAPACK: Linear Algebra PACKage, http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/d69/dgeqrf_8f.html)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hyperref`'s built-in commands `\url` and `\href` (see below). I've reduced your code to a true MWE, since the important part is `hyperref`.

[image: linking]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
% \hypersetup{draft} <-- remove this
\begin{document}
The purpose of these notes is to provide an introduction to stochastic differential equations (SDEs) (LAPACK: Linear Algebra PACKage, \url{http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/d69/dgeqrf_8f.html}). Here's \href{http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/d69/dgeqrf_8f.html}{the same link}, just another title.
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ TeXincian, I am writing two-column springer paper, when I use \url{}  with long URL, it does not split it correctly.

Comment: @user137684 Have a look at this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49791/124577.