# Split long URL in two-column paper

Tags: hyperref

I am writing two-column springer paper, when I use \url{} with long URL, it does not split it correctly, I tried some solutions described in this link [tex.stackexchange.com/a/49791/124577.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49791/124577.)  but they did not work for me.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass[natbib,twocolumn]{svjour3}          % 
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%Packages-------------------------------------------------------
% \usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX system
%
% insert here the call for the packages your document requires
%\usepackage{latexsym}
% etc.
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{refstyle}
%\usepackage{amsfonts,eqnarray}
\usepackage{empheq,etoolbox}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}% <-- new
\usepackage{ragged2e}% <-- new
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\newcommand\hmmax{0}
\newcommand{\bmmax}{3}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text
\newcounter{resume}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{stfloats}
%---------------------------------------------------------------
% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
% Update display of subequation numbering (Xy) > (X.y)
\patchcmd{\subequations}% <cmd>
  {\theparentequation\alph{equation}}% <search>
  {\theparentequation.\alph{equation}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tria}{Tria}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
%end Packages--------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}


\lipsum[1-2]
\ul{B. Second procedure : differentiating the QR algorithm}\\
We are using MATLAB version R2015b, which uses LAPACK library. and the MATLAB expression [Q,R] = qr(A,0) returns the output of LAPACK's dgeqrf routine (Linear Algebra PACKage, \url{http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/d69/dgeqrf_8f.html}). The dgeqrf algorithm compute the QR
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: We need a MWE to know WHY it's not working. A simple test I did with \documentclass[twocolumn]{article} did not produce that problem.

Comment: @ Elad Den, I have updated my question by inserting a MWE.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{fussy}

\parbox{8.5cm}{\fussy
We are using MATLAB version 2015b, which uses LA\-PACK
libray and the  MATLAB zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz
 zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz
zzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
\url{http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/d32/dgerfs_8f.html}
The GEQRF zzz zzz.}


\section{sloppy}

\parbox{8.5cm}{\sloppy
We are using MATLAB version 2015b, which uses LA\-PACK
libray and the  MATLAB zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz
 zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz
zzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
\url{http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/d32/dgerfs_8f.html}
The GEQRF zzz zzz.}

\section{fussy with hfill}

\parbox{8.5cm}{\fussy
We are using MATLAB version 2015b, which uses LA\-PACK
libray and the  MATLAB zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz
 zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz zzzz
zzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz \hfill
\url{http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/d32/dgerfs_8f.html}
The GEQRF zzz zzz.}




\end{document}
```