# Breaking long links in bibliography using REVTeX and Bibtex

Tags: hyperref, revtex

I'm writing an article using the REVTeX documentclass, and use hyperref. The problem is that when I add URLs to my references, the linked titles aren't broken at all.

Minimal example:
.tex file:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\cite{reference, reference2}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

references:

```
@TECHREPORT{reference,
    AUTHOR      = {Firstname Lastname},
    TITLE       = {Extremely long and complicated title of something I want to reference several times in my very interesting article},    
    INSTITUTION = {Institution},
    YEAR        = {2013},
    URL         = {http://url/}
}

@TECHREPORT{reference2,
    AUTHOR      = {Firstname Lastname},
    TITLE       = {Regular reference},    
    INSTITUTION = {Institution},
    YEAR        = {2013},
    FILE        = {http://url/},
}
```

Compile using `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex`, `dvipdf`.

The result:[image]

Does anyone know of a way to remedy this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).  Your sample code wraps correctly for me.  Are you packages up-to-date?

Comment: Your code works for me. Maybe you use some old package versions.

Comment: How can I check what package versions I have? I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, using the default versions from the repos

Comment: @AndrewSwann Could you tell me what versions of the packages you have? I added `\listfiles` to my preamble, and got `hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2`, `revsymb4-1.sty 2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r`, `natbib.sty 2010/09/13 8.31b`, `url.sty 2006/04/12  ver 3.3`, and lots of other packages I don't know if is relevant.

Comment: `revtex4-1.cls 2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r` and `hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m` are probably the most relevant.  May be also relevent is the fact that I compile with `pdflatex`.

Comment: Aha, I need to compile using latex, bibtex and dvipdf. Could you try that? It breaks correctly using pdflatex for me as well.

Comment: Using `latex` gives the problem.  `breakurl` solutions as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20768/15925 would be expected to help, but revtex writes an `\href` command in the bibliography rather than `\url`.  Now `breakurl` provides `\burlalt` that has the same syntax as `\href`, but (a) I can't get the `\burlalt` command to work - it produces compilation errors even in simple `article` documents, (b) I don't see how to make the substitution of `\href` by `\burlalt`, except via an external processing of the `.bbl`. I think you are going to have to use `pdflatex`

Comment: I have been thinking about it, and I don't see any reason that I have to compile using latex, so I'll just use pdflatex. The REVTeX guide recommends latex, but... Thanks anyway!

Comment: This should be reopened, as it's still an issue without a solution. Note that the long links prevail on APS's end, and the editors of the journals request these are fixed by the submitter.

Comment: "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors" No kidding, it's been closed. Why are these questions left "up" so that anyone with the same problem (like me) will find them in google? If the question is left up, you might as well allow people to  leave answers...

Comment: Seriously, why bother closing a question like this? It's a perfectly valid question, contains a working example, and other users (me) have this problem. Specifically, I compile locally fine using pdflatex, but when submitting to the arxiv, the file is remotely compiled and I get this line-wrapping problem. It would have been great to have had other answers available to help me solve the problem