# Text goes beyond paper marge

Tags: horizontal-alignment

my problem is best illustrated in the picture below: the text won't center between the paper marge. I've used some commands from related problems on this website but nothing happens when I run it. The text remains as such:[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  { \textbf{\underline{Random text to show that the right side of the text goes beyond the paper marge and don't know how to fix this} }}
\end{center} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: See my [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262317/16967) from today to question [Line breaking with hyperref href with an underline in itemize](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262306/16967).