# Line breaking with adjustment but no hyphenation

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, hyphenation, dvips, dvi-mode

I have the following situation: very long function names that are put into text with a macro `\fun{this-is-a-very-long-fuction-name}`.  This macro includes indexing, but then finally puts the function name in bold as a hyperlink.  I want to have LaTeX do line breaks for adjustment, but break the emboldened name only at the hyphens without adding a hyphen; the hyperlink must work.  How can I do that?  Specifically, my `\fun` macro is

```
\def\fun#1{\funbb{#1}{#1}\indexfun{#1}}
\def\funbb#1#2{\hyperlink{#1}{\textbf{#2}}}
\def\indexfun#1{\index{#1@\textbf{#1}}}
```

The rest of the document should have normal line breaks with adjustment and hyphenation.

---

**Edit**: Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\geometry{total={115.84mm,195mm}}
\def\fun#1{\hyperlink{#1}{\textbf{#1}}}
\begin{document}
we need to include the lengths of all months from Tishri until \fun{last-month-of-hebrew-year}
\end{document}
```

When compiled with `latex`, it produces the following in the DVI:

[image: DVI output]

Note that it breaks the function name after the "he" of "hebrew". Also, it is not a hyperlink, as it should be.

Comment: latex doesn't hyphenate hyphenated words, it just breaks at the existing hyphens, so it isn't clear what you need other than teh default behaviour.

Comment: For example, last-month-of-hebrew-year gets hyphenated after the "he" of "hebrew" and it is not a hyperlink

Comment: @EdwardReingold Thanks, I assume you are using `latex` and not `pdflatex`, as I was able to reproduce this only with the former. I have edited the question to include your example, and voted to reopen it. (BTW, there is a warning message in the output that says “Package hyperref Warning: You have enabled option `breaklinks'. But driver `hdvips.def' does not suppport this. Expect trouble with the link areas of broken links.”)

Comment: That explains the broken link; but the bad hyphenation?  Is there a way around the two problems?

Comment: Using `pdflatex` instead of `latex` is the only solution I know of (and it solves both problems; also you don't need the `[breaklinks]` option as it's set automatically). I don't know if you have compelling reasons to go the DVI route; working around those reasons (so that you can directly produce PDF) may be easier than fixing this. Maybe someone with more knowledge of the inner workings of the `hyperref` package will post an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I must use dvips, so I cannot use pdflatex (which would require many, many changes to my manuscript).

Comment: (@ShreevatsaR).  I made some experiments with TeX’s tracing facilities, and it turned out that, when the `hdvips` driver is used, discretionaries are *not* added after explicit hyphens, contrary to what normally happens (cf. _The TeXbook_, p. 286, sixth to fourth line from the bottom).  Since the `\hyphenchar` is not changed, in all probability this is achieved by typesetting the link in restricted horizontal mode and subsequently `\unhbox`ing it; in any case, the lack of discretionaries fully explains the fact that the word “hebrew” gets hyphenated (see p. 454, esp. ll. -8 to -5).

Comment: Cf., indeed, the definition of `\pdf@rect` in `hdvips.def`.

Comment: Via the related questions I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20768/how-to-allow-line-break-in-a-long-hyperlink-in-a-pdf-compiled-by-latex-dvips-ps2). Some of those answers may work for you. Unfortunately none of them do exactly what's asked here, but the implementation of the suggested `breakurl` package may have some clues…

Comment: Is there a way to set \hyphenchar to nil temporarily in my \fun macro?

Comment: Do you have any reason not to compile with `pdflatex`?

Comment: Yes: I need pstricks for the (many, many) diagrams.

Comment: Any news here ?